# "Each of us has the plague within him" from The Plague by Albert Camus

Tags: french-language, albert-camus, the-plague

I'm reading *[The Plague](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Plague)* By Albert Camus. I'm not getting few things that Tarrou said when talking of his previous life to all to Dr. Bernard Rieux.

First, he talks about his father, mother, and all. One day his visits the court and sees everything. In his talk, he says,

> And thus I came to understand that I, anyhow, had had plague through all those long years in which, paradoxically enough, I'd believed with all my soul that I was fighting it. I learned that I had an indirect hand in the deaths of thousands of people; that I'd even brought about their death by approving of act and principles which could only end that way. Others did not seem embarrassed by such thoughts, or anyhow never voiced them of their own accord.

How did Tarrou have his hand on thousands of peoples?

Further, he said, "Each of us has the plague within him." I don't understand quite what Tarrou talking about. In court, I know his father was appealing for the man's death and so it can be said, that his father has his hand in many death. But, how is everyone responsible for many deaths?